# identifying type of data in tableview

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a table view in which data is loaded from a web service. The web service has 4 dictionaries each containing a different format of data. Dict 1 has a text data(row 1 of table), dict 2 has image data(row 2), dict 3 has audio data(row 3), dict 4 has video data(row 4). All the data is loaded from a web service. The web service returns a path for image, audio and video data which reside on other hostings. Like image and audio data reside on amazon s3. The url for image and audio is an amazon s3 url and video is also a url(path) of the file. Now i want that when user taps row 1, the text should be displayed on another view in a text view which i have already done. When row 2 is tapped the corresponding image should be shown on another view in a imageview. When row 3 is tapped, the user should be able to watch the video on another view and when row 4 is tapped, the user should be able to play the audio file(which is a path of file from amazon s3). How should this be done. Thanks in advance.

Comment: All are four are in fixed order, in any circumstances they will not be changed?

Comment: what about their keys? all four are having same tags or you can customize according to your wish?

Answer (score 0):

It is simple..
Just define tags for the cells accordingly.

Like 1 = Text Cell, 2=image cell etc.

And in cellForRowAtIndexPath, set the tag of the cell accordingly.

Then in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, call the cellForRowAtIndexPath with the selected indexPAth.

In the returned cell, check the tag and accordingly take your action..